# How to find slow queries on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I'm developing graph application on AgensGraph, and suffering poor performance of transaction.
I want to list long-term queries from log of AgensGraph.

How to extract slow queries from log?

Answer (score 1):

You can try statement log of AgensGraph.

First, change parameters on "postgresql.conf"

```
log_duration = on
log_statement = 'all'
```

Second, restart AgensGraph.

```
$ ag_ctl stop
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
$ ag_ctl start
server starting
```

Finally, run queries and check log file.

```
agens=# set graph_path to graph;
SET
agens=# create view temp as select gs from generate_series( 1, 1000000 ) gs;
CREATE VIEW
agens=# load from temp as gs create (:n{id:gs});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1000000, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# \quit
```

Filter statement on long duration values.

```
LOG:  statement: set graph_path to graph;
LOG:  duration: 0.296 ms
LOG:  statement: create view temp as select gs from generate_series( 1, 1000000 ) gs;
LOG:  duration: 9.859 ms
LOG:  statement: load from temp as gs create (:n{id:gs});
LOG:  duration: 20194.808 ms
```